# WCF wsHttpBinding with Transport Security

Tags: wcf, security, wcf-binding

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpsecurity) on MSDN as well as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734679.aspx) states the when dealing with `wsHttpBinding`, Transport security is handled via SSL.

On the [MSDN page about SSL and WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734679.aspx) it states that when a ServiceHost is hosted within IIS, the ServiceHost leaves the SSL to be handled by IIS.

Would this not imply that if `binding/securityMode="Transport"`, that any `wsHttpBinding/binding/security/transport/clientCredentialType` values would be ignored as none of their options are  needed to set up the SSL transport?

It even appears to to say something to this effect [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731884.aspx) when it states

> "When setting the security mode to TransportWithMessageCredential, the
>   transport determines the actual mechanism that provides the
>   transport-level security. For example, the HTTP protocol uses Secure
>   Sockets Layer (SSL) over HTTP (HTTPS). Therefore, setting the
>   ClientCredentialType property of any transport security object (such
>   as HttpTransportSecurity) is ignored. In other words, you can only set
>   the ClientCredentialType of the message security object (for the
>   WSHttpBinding binding, the NonDualMessageSecurityOverHttp object)."

And yet [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734679.aspx) for `basicHttpBinding` and for `wsHttpBinding`, they both categorically emphasis with examples that if security mode is set to Transport, set the binding/transport/clientCredentialType to something (eg: Windows).

What's the exact difference between `Transport` and `TransportWithMessageCredential`?

And do I have the wrong end of the stick, and the `SecurityType` enum (`None|Message|Transport|Mixed`) is not just for privacy, but for authentication to the server?

If Transport security is provided by SSL encryption, how did Authentication/Authorization get tangled into this stage?

Thanks immensely for helping me get a better picture of how this all fits together.

Comment: Great question. To bad no answers followed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the TransportWithMessageCredential is kind of "best of both worlds". The channel is secured on the transport layer so there is a secure connection between client and service  (which can be very fast, implemented in hardware), plus the message is signed with message credentials so it can survive multiple hops before arriving at the service (validated in WCF).

And of course, you can use message credentials which are not supported on the transport layer, username/password for example.